# ¿Como quitar slash invertido en json?

Tags: php, json

Al ejecutar este código:

```
    $array =array();
    $sqli=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'dbuser', 'pass', 'db');
    $query = mysqli_query($sqli,"SELECT * FROM usuarios");
    while ($fila = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $res=array('nombre'=>$fila["nombre"],'tipo'=>$fila["tipo"] 'contraseña'=>$fila["user"]);
        array_push($array,$res);
    }
    header("Content-type:application/json");
    echo json_encode($array);
```

me obtiene este resultado:

```
{"nombre":"admin","tipo":"1","contrase\u00f1a":"$2y$10$H5GU7rN38jo3n\/eJW6KMHuovnCFYymi8GrQpshuhowWxYVZdq8r2S"}]
```

me genera slashes invertidos despues de un `/` y me cambia la `ñ` por su entidad html ¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto?

Comment: Inténtalo haciendo echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); aunque no estoy seguro si una propiedad pueda tener carácteres especiales...

Comment: Establece el charset UTF8 en la conexión a la base de datos, creo que ahí está el problema. Antes de lanzar la consulta: `mysqli_set_charset($sqli, "utf8");`

Comment: @A.Cedano puedes confirmarme si una propiedad puede tener como parte del nombre carácteres especiales?

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que el problema es de codificación, sea al crear la conexión a la base de datos, sea en los datos mismos. Prueba con lo que te dije del charset en el comentario anterior, **y no cambies nada más**, deja tu `json_encode($array);` tal cual. Prueba así y comenta el resultado. También, pon la codificación en el header: **`header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");`** Haciendo esas dos cosas debería funcionar normal.

Comment: @CamiloVasquez ¿te refieres a si una propiedad de un JSON puede tener caracteres especiales?

Comment: me funcionó el  `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`  con el problema de la `ñ` pero aun me saltan los slashes invertidos

Comment: @A.Cedano exacto {'contraseña': 'micontraseña'} ... se puede?

Comment: Claro que se puede @CamiloVasquez, aunque es bueno tratar de evitar letras como la `ñ` (al menos yo así lo hago). En nombres de tablas, columnas, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano por eso te pregunté por que siempre me enseñaron a omitir la ñ en todo...muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la opción `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` para que no escape los `/`.

En cuanto a la `ñ` te lo esta convirtiendo a unicode, puedes forzar tambien para que no lo convierta con `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

```
// JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES => 64
// JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE => 256
// JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES + JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE => 320


$arrayName = array('Contraseña' => '$2y$10$H5GU7rN38jo3n/eJW6KMHuovnCFYymi8GrQpshuhowWxYVZdq8r2S');
echo json_encode($arrayName, 320);
// {"Contraseña":"$2y$10$H5GU7rN38jo3n/eJW6KMHuovnCFYymi8GrQpshuhowWxYVZdq8r2S"}
echo json_encode($arrayName);
// {"Contrase\u00f1a":"$2y$10$H5GU7rN38jo3n\/eJW6KMHuovnCFYymi8GrQpshuhowWxYVZdq8r2S"}
```

Más informacion en http://php.net/manual/es/json.constants.php

Comment: Creo que es un problema a nivel de la conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Aun que así fuera `json_encode()` escapa esos caracteres por defecto, puede hacer la prueba, puse un ejemplo de comparacion en la respuesta para copiar pegar.

Comment: gracias me funcionó la combinación `json_encode($array,320);`

Comment: Creo que el problema se resolvería más de raíz estableciendo la codificación adecuada @Xerif, tanto en la conexión como en el `header`. Al no establecer una codificación uniforme surge el problema y entonces hay que actuar sobre la conversión en el JSON. Si tuviera que presentar más datos aparte del JSON tendría que convertir o escapar caracteres otra vez.

Comment: @A.Cedano La codificación de la bd y de la conexión parece correcta y acorde (desconocemos cual usa) pues le esta devolviendo una `ñ` que `json_encode()` convierte a `unicode` por defecto. Yo sinceramente dejaría que `json_encode` espara los datos normales, pero desconozco el contexto del OP y la finalidad de los datos, por lo que me limito a aportar la solución que solicita.